# Glassfish 3 Cluster and Local init scripts

Tags: linux, cluster, glassfish, init.d

I'm trying to set-up a Glassfish 3.1.1 Cluster for testing purposes.

Currently, I've got 2 hosts with Glassfish 3.1.1 installed. 
I've set-up a DAS domain on host1, and followed this guide to create the cluster: http://javadude.wordpress.com/2011/04/25/glassfish-3-1-clustering-tutorial/

This all worked quite well, and I've got 2 instances running on the 2 hosts which I can start/stop etc from the DAS.

However I want to set-up an init script for the individual instances on their relevant host to ensure that the instance starts correctly on a reboot.

I've found the command:

```
asadmin start-instance --node host1_node1 host1_inst1
asadmin start-instance --node host2_node1 host2_inst1
```

However this command keeps asking me for a admin username and admin password. 
I've tried a `asadmin --host host1 --port 4898 login`, which saves the details correctly. However I'm still being prompted for a username/password on running the `start-instance` command.

Any ideas???

Cheers
Gavin

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
asadmin start-local-instance
asadmin stop-local-instance
```

on the cluster nodes.

The DAS still needs to be started with `asadmin start-domain`.